# awk: how to extract strings directly into bash array?

Tags: bash, awk

let's say I have this:

```
ARRAY=()
NUM_EXTRACTED=$(cat somefile.txt | awk '/magic/{i++; print > i "_extracted.txt"} END {print i}')
for (( i=1; i<=$NUM_EXTRACTED; i++)); do
  LINE=$(cat "$i"_extracted.txt)
  ARRAY+=("$LINE")
done
```

this script takes all lines in somefile.txt that contain the word 'magic' and put them into the array ARRAY

how can I fill ARRAY directly, without storing the lines out into temporary files?

Comment: can you provide few lines from somefile.txt

Comment: If you don't have to use awk, there's mapfile.

Answer (score 3):

In `bash`, that would be with the `readarray` builtin:

```
readarray -t myarray < <(grep magic somefile.txt)
```

More generally, if you're using a loop to process text in a shell, chances are you're doing it wrong. Using shell arrays is often a sign that you need a proper programming language as well (or do the whole thing in `awk`).